# Passing a subfunction name as an argument in a function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform that has a listbox of sheet names in the workbook and has three buttons: one deletes all worksheets selected in the listbox, one just clears those sheets, and the other removes charts from that sheet. I currently have three sub functions that look nearly identical, as each just runs a single subfunction on a loop, based on the selected button:

```
Sub DeleteSheets() 'Removes sheets selected by user in ListBox

    For k = 0 To sheetNameListBox.ListCount - 1      
     If sheetNameListBox.Selected(k) = True Then     
      DeleteSheet sheetNameListBox.List(k)           
     End If
    Next k

End Sub

Sub ClearSheets() 'Clears sheets selected by user in ListBox

    For k = 0 To sheetNameListBox.ListCount - 1       
     If sheetNameListBox.Selected(k) = True Then      
      ClearSheet sheetNameListBox.List(k)              
     End If
    Next k

End Sub

Sub DeleteCharts() 'Removes charts from sheets selected by user

    For k = 0 To sheetNameListBox.ListCount - 1   
     If sheetNameListBox.Selected(k) = True Then  
      DeleteChart sheetNameListBox.List(k)        
     End If
    Next k

End Sub
```

To solve this problem, I decided to develop a subfunction like this:

```
Sub RemoveSheetData(removeType As String)

        For k = 0 To sheetNameListBox.ListCount - 1   
         If sheetNameListBox.Selected(k) = True Then  
          If removeType = "DeleteSheet" Then DeleteSheet sheetNameListBox.List(k)
          If removeType = "ClearSheet" Then ClearSheet sheetNameListBox.List(k)
          If removeType = "DeleteChart" Then DeleteChart sheetNameListBox.List(k)
         End If
        Next k

End Sub
```

This seems also to be inefficient as I have to have three cases for each. Is there a way that I can directly input the name of the function I wish to call, and have it run?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer blatantly stolen from [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19574-Solved-A-function-as-a-variable-Pass-function-as-parameter-function-pointer)

```
Sub test() 
    Dim ftnName As String 
    Dim argument As String 
    Dim result As String 

    ftnName = "myFunction" 
    argument = "cat" 

    result = Application.Run(ftnName, argument) 

    MsgBox result 
End Sub 

Function myFunction(inString As String) As String 
    myFunction = inString & " has " & Len(inString) & " letters." 
End Function
```